# How to get if or unless statement to work over multiple lines in erb template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chef-infra, erb

I'm trying to write in some logic to a erb template in a chef cookbook. I have the following, which I thought would work. At the moment the attribute there is nil, but it's not skipping the whole block like I thought it would. How do I get the top statement to cause the template reader to skip the whole block?

```
    <% unless node['base']['logstash-forwarder']['nginx'].nil? %>
      <%= "{" %>
      <%= "\"paths\": [" %>
      <% node['base']['logstash-forwarder']['nginx'].each do |path| %>
        <% unless path.equal? node['base']['logstash-forwarder']['nginx'].last %>
        <%= "\"#{path}\"," %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    <%= "\"#{node['base']['logstash-forwarder']['nginx'].last}\"" %>
    <%= " ]," %>
    <%= "\"fields\": { \"type\": \"nginx-access\" }" %>
    <%= "}" %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: He has <% end %> for the outer unless, an each loop and an inner unless. The Ruby interpreter would have complained if there were a mismatch.

Comment: Logically, the code looks fine. I even ran a simplified version in console to check the structure, and mine skips. The thing to check is that your input really is what you think it is (i.e. node['base']['logstash-forwarder']['nginx'] really is nil). Adding a simple <%= puts node['base']['logstash-forwarder']['nginx'] %> would do the trick.

Comment: My mistake. This actually does work. There was something up the line that was causing the error I was getting. Sorry for the false alarm.

Comment: On a side note, it looks like you are making JSON here, which Erb isn't a good fit for. Jbuilder might make more sense, but I haven't used it for creating inline JSON for JS stuff within the HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Your exact code above works precisely as expected in ERB, see:

```
[122] pry(main)> e = ERB.new <<'EOI'
[122] pry(main)*  <% unless node['base']['logstash-forwarder']['nginx'].nil? %>
[122] pry(main)*       <%= "{" %>
[122] pry(main)*       <%= "\"paths\": [" %>
[122] pry(main)*       <% node['base']['logstash-forwarder']['nginx'].each do |path| %>
[122] pry(main)*         <% unless path.equal? node['base']['logstash-forwarder']['nginx'].last %>
[122] pry(main)*         <%= "\"#{path}\"," %>
[122] pry(main)*         <% end %>
[122] pry(main)*       <% end %>
[122] pry(main)*     <%= "\"#{node['base']['logstash-forwarder']['nginx'].last}\"" %>
[122] pry(main)*     <%= " ]," %>
[122] pry(main)*     <%= "\"fields\": { \"type\": \"nginx-access\" }" %>
[122] pry(main)*     <%= "}" %>
[122] pry(main)*   <% end %>
[122] pry(main)* EOI
=> #<ERB:0x007fe74bb35ff8
 @encoding=#<Encoding:UTF-8>,
 @filename=nil,
 @lineno=0,
 @safe_level=nil,
 @src=
  "#coding:UTF-8\n_erbout = ''; _erbout.concat \" \";  unless node['base']['logstash-forwarder']['nginx'].nil? ; _erbout.concat \"\\n      \"\n; _erbout.concat(( \"{\" ).to_s); _erbout.concat \"\\n      \"\n; _erbout.concat(( \"\\\"paths\\\": [\" ).to_s); _erbout.concat \"\\n      \"\n;  node['base']['logstash-forwarder']['nginx'].each do |path| ; _erbout.concat \"\\n        \"\n;  unless path.equal? node['base']['logstash-forwarder']['nginx'].last ; _erbout.concat \"\\n        \"\n; _erbout.concat(( \"\\\"\#{path}\\\",\" ).to_s); _erbout.concat \"\\n        \"\n;  end ; _erbout.concat \"\\n      \"\n;  end ; _erbout.concat \"\\n    \"\n; _erbout.concat(( \"\\\"\#{node['base']['logstash-forwarder']['nginx'].last}\\\"\" ).to_s); _erbout.concat \"\\n    \"\n; _erbout.concat(( \" ],\" ).to_s); _erbout.concat \"\\n    \"\n; _erbout.concat(( \"\\\"fields\\\": { \\\"type\\\": \\\"nginx-access\\\" }\" ).to_s); _erbout.concat \"\\n    \"\n; _erbout.concat(( \"}\" ).to_s); _erbout.concat \"\\n  \"\n;  end ; _erbout.concat \"\\n\"\n; _erbout.force_encoding(__ENCODING__)">
[123] pry(main)> node = { 'base' => { 'logstash-forwarder' => {}}}
=> {"base"=>{"logstash-forwarder"=>{}}}
[124] pry(main)> path = nil
=> nil
[125] pry(main)> e.result binding
=> " \n"
[126] pry(main)>
```

So the problem is either that Chef does something weird (seems unlikely) or your `node` isn't as `nil?` as you think it is.

#### Update

Reading between the lines, especially at your `.each` and `.last` calls, could it be possible that your `node['base']['logstash-forwarder']['nginx']` is not actually `nil` but rather `[]`?

If so, change your `.nil?` check to a `.empty?`